# using forEach to iterate over varArgs

Tags: java, java-8

Can I use `forEach()` or `stream()` on varArgs ?

```
   protected void getSomeIds (List<String>... varArgs) {
     for(List lst:varArgs) {
     System.out.println("This works");
    }
   //Following does not compile 
    varArgs.forEach();
   // nor 
    varArgs.stream();
   }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Varargs behave similarly to arrays, so you can get a `Stream` of the varargs using `Stream.of` :

```
Stream<List<String>> stream = Stream.of (varArgs);
```

And you can iterate over them with :

```
Stream.of(varArgs).forEach (...);
```

Comment: Since, `varArgs` is actually already an array, `Arrays.stream(…)` should be preferred to avoid accidentally creating a single-element stream holding one array. `Stream.of(…)` is the preferred way if you actually have multiple arguments, e.g. `Stream.of(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Comment: ok ,this is making sense to me now. Thanks Holger and Eran

Comment: thanks @eran. btw, for android devs, don't forget to use [android-retrostream](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams) if you also wants to support api below 24

Answer (score -4):

You are confusing syntax.   Try this:

```
for(List lst:varArgs) {
    lst.forEach(str -> System.out.println(str));
}
```